# How to modify this python script to print into a file?

Tags: python

I saw this script:

https://gist.github.com/koenbollen/645947

however I wanted the print function to print into a file instead to the console.

How is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Please look at [ask] and how to  provide a [mcve].

Comment: you could just do `f = open("filename.txt", "w")` and replace all the `print` with `f.write(texttowrite)`

Comment: I tried that, however there will be an error then:
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Answer (score 0):

Print in python has more parameters.
This should do it for you.

[Http://Www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php](http://print%20command)

```
Outfile = open ('new.txt','w')
print (val, file=Outfile, end='')
```

Comment: the script was written for python2 and causes an error with that code.